# Getting demographics details of people who have liked a post on a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get demographics information (mainly Location) regarding the people who like a particular post on a page owned by someone else.

For example, for a post on CocaCola's FB Page, I'm trying to get the reactions for a particular post by using this following string in the Graph API Explorer: `40796308305_10155753622733306/?fields=reactions{name,link,type}`

Is there a way to also get location of the person who reacted to the post?

I'm using Graph API v2.6

Comment: Of course there isn’t - it’s called privacy.